# Match rotation of instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm quite new to blender and i've been trying to recreate this DNA using only geometry nodes:
[image]

The problem is that i still didn't figure out how to make the straight forms in the middle match the curve of the double helix
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the *Instance on Points* node responsible for spawning the bridges, and adjust the rotation of the instances. Based on my knowledge of DNA, I think you want to rotate those instances around $z$ axis, aligning them to the offset from the $z$ axis, so the $xy$ offset - that's why I multiply the *Position* by $<1, 1, 0>$ vector, to remove the $z$ component of the vector:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can connect two curves like this:

[image]

hope it helps.

There must be an easier way, but my head isn't working today :(